# python flask app.run how do I automatically in python code stop flask after all tests are completed

Tags: python, flask

I have a code which already works fine and process my stuff

```
    app.secret_key = 'my Top Secret'
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

but when all my tests are completed how do I stop flask from running in code not from command line using python code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no apparent connection between the OP's question and the OP's resolution. Too many facts not in evidence.

Answer (score 0):

THis isi the answer

```
public_url = ngrok.connect(port=5900, proto='tcp', config_path='~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml')
```

Comment: Thanks but I cant use ngrok due to our security. I have an AWS server .  I believe I will use Twilio built in validator instead